# Could the Cowboy Bebop movie be set a few years after the series?

Tags: cowboy-bebop

**THE DESCRIPTION HAS MANY BIG SPOILERS. You have been warned.**

I have read many posts and reviews where it said that the creators of Cowboy Bebop intended the movie to be between sessions 22 and 23. There are a few questions on this site which ask specifically where the movie is placed chronologically with the series and people have placed emphasis on the fact that chronological order is not very important to most of the series…

> …and that the main reason the movie is said to be before 23 is because Ed and Ein are still with the Bebop in the movie, whereas in the series they leave soon after 23.

> Now it is a popular interpretation of the ending that Spike died and I don't want to start that debate (yet), but assuming he lives (and is just sleeping at the end like Watanabe semi-jokingly says in an interview only last year), I believe that the movie could be set after the events of the series, perhaps soon after or a few years, Ed and Ein are back, and Ed seems to return to places a few years after she leaves (as the matron at the orphanage on earth says).

Is there any evidence to back up this view?

> Also I request that anyone answering remember that my crucial assumption here is that Spike lives, so please try not to start that debate as I'm very aware many people believe he does not and often vehemently defend their view. Think of this as a hypothetical "if he lives, could the movie be set a while after the end of the series?"

Comment: I think after the series, everything is hypothetical and you can pretty much make up any sequence of events you want in order to connect it to the beginning of the movie.

Answer (score 3):

According to the wiki.

> The later Cowboy Bebop movie Knockin' on Heaven's Door is said to be set between episodes 22 and 23 of the original TV series, but Shinichiro Watanabe will not rule out the idea that the movie is a dream.

So I would say its definitely not after the movie since the creators think it was either a dream or between the old episodes.